# Execute Terraform Plan with AWS assume_role and non-default AWS credentials

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, aws-codepipeline

I'm trying to run terraform plan locally with a non-default aws credentials profile, where my default profile will not work. I also need to use `assume_role` in terraform `provider "aws"`. My code looks something like this:

```
provider "aws" {
  version             = "~> 2.45"
  region              = "us-east-1"
  profile             = <profile name>
  allowed_account_ids = [<account_id>]
  assume_role {
    role_arn = "arn:aws:iam::<account id>:role/<role name>"
  }
}
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
Error: The role "arn:aws:iam::<account_id>:role/<role_name>" cannot be assumed.

  There are a number of possible causes of this - the most common are:
    * The credentials used in order to assume the role are invalid
    * The credentials do not have appropriate permission to assume the role
    * The role ARN is not valid
```

Interestingly, when I put access_key and secret_key in the provider like this:

```
provider "aws" {
  version             = "~> 2.45"
  region              = "us-east-1"
  access_key = <aws access key>
  secret_key = <aws secret key>
  assume_role {
    role_arn = "arn:aws:iam::<account_id>:role/<role_name>"
  }
}
```

terraform plan works fine. I've double checked my aws credentials file several time and it's setup correctly, but I'm not sure why terraform plan doesn't work.
I've also tried deleting the `assume_role` parameter in `provider "aws"` when i have `access_key` and `secret_key` in the file, and terraform plan works fine, which means i don't need the `assume_role`. however, if i use the profile from aws credentials without `assume_role` in terraform file, i'm getting:

```
Error: error using credentials to get account ID: error calling sts:GetCallerIdentity: SignatureDoesNotMatch: The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your AWS Secret Access Key and signing method. Consult the service documentation for details.
        status code: 403, request id:
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need amend the `Trust Policy` on the `IAM Role` like below

[How to use trust policies with IAM roles](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/how-to-use-trust-policies-with-iam-roles/)

```json
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::111122223333:user/<Your username>"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
      "Condition": {}
    }
  ]
}
```

Once you update the `Trust Policy` on the `IAM Role` you can verify this via [assume-role](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/sts/assume-role.html) command

```sh
aws sts assume-role --role-arn arn:aws:iam::123456789012:role/xaccounts3access --role-session-name s3-access-example
```

You would receive something like:

```
{
    "AssumedRoleUser": {
        "AssumedRoleId": "AROA3XFRBF535PLBIFPI4:s3-access-example",
        "Arn": "arn:aws:sts::123456789012:assumed-role/xaccounts3access/s3-access-example"
    },
    "Credentials": {
        "SecretAccessKey": "9drTJvcXLB89EXAMPLELB8923FB892xMFI",
        "SessionToken": "AQoXdzELDDY//////////wEaoAK1wvxJY12r2IrDFT2IvAzTCn3zHoZ7YNtpiQLF0MqZye/qwjzP2iEXAMPLEbw/m3hsj8VBTkPORGvr9jM5sgP+w9IZWZnU+LWhmg+a5fDi2oTGUYcdg9uexQ4mtCHIHfi4citgqZTgco40Yqr4lIlo4V2b2Dyauk0eYFNebHtYlFVgAUj+7Indz3LU0aTWk1WKIjHmmMCIoTkyYp/k7kUG7moeEYKSitwQIi6Gjn+nyzM+PtoA3685ixzv0R7i5rjQi0YE0lf1oeie3bDiNHncmzosRM6SFiPzSvp6h/32xQuZsjcypmwsPSDtTPYcs0+YN/8BRi2/IcrxSpnWEXAMPLEXSDFTAQAM6Dl9zR0tXoybnlrZIwMLlMi1Kcgo5OytwU=",
        "Expiration": "2016-03-15T00:05:07Z",
        "AccessKeyId": "ASIAJEXAMPLEXEG2JICEA"
    }
}
```

Comment: I already have this trust policy on the IAM role. The assume-role command works fine in terminal, but i still couldn't run terraform plan without having my access_key and secret_key in file :(

Comment: @Mell instead of adding the credentials in the code, can you try exporting(like export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=adsa and AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=asdsa)them in the current shell and then run `terraform plan`

Comment: @Mell one more thing when you are using `secrets` inside the code, you are not using `allowed_account_ids` I would check if both are correct and role/secrets/account_id. Last but not least make sure the time on your system is synced.

Comment: ah yes when i try exporting `access key` and `secret key` it works! Really confusing how using `profile` doesn't work. I've double checked and role/secrets/account_id are correct. What do you mean to make sure time on my system is synced? sorry for the questions i'm a terraform newbie

Comment: @Mell never mind if this works via exporting the keys, the time sync can't be the issue.[Terraform AWS provider unable to assume role using profile that assumes a role itself #8052](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/issues/8052). So you can stick to exporting the credentials and using the `assume_role` inside the provider.

Comment: The fix got released in [provider: Authentication updates for Terraform AWS Provider v3.0.0 #14077](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/pull/14077) so either upgrade the provider or use exported credentials.

Comment: i've upgraded the version but still got the same error :( i'll stick to exporting the credentials for now. Thanks!

Comment: @Mell which version you are using now? and what's the error, can you share?

Comment: my aws provider version is 3.23.0
the error is:
`Error: error configuring Terraform AWS Provider: IAM Role (arn:aws:iam::<account id>:role/<role name>) cannot be assumed.

There are a number of possible causes of this - the most common are:
  * The credentials used in order to assume the role are invalid
  * The credentials do not have appropriate permission to assume the role
  * The role ARN is not valid

Error: NoCredentialProviders: no valid providers in chain. Deprecated.
        For verbose messaging see aws.Config.CredentialsChainVerboseErrors`

Comment: @Mell now it depends on you either you stick to exporting the credentials, or we can debug, can you check if there are any other vars set in env via `env|grep -i aws`. Seems like it got introduced again in `3.26` [Provider assume role block with profile no longer works with 3.26.0 #17353](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/issues/17353). It keeps popping back so you stick to exporting the secrets.

Comment: Nope there's no other vars set in env with this command. I've also tried commenting out my default aws credentials and set the aws credentials I'm trying to use as the default, so this might not be related to using non-default profile.

Comment: @Mell I used the same provider `3.23`, it works fine for me  check here [gist](https://gist.github.com/toddlers/6b54ff01cb8e8eb5ebdfd28c401b58c1)

Comment: ah i see. not sure which part of my credentials is wrong, i guess i'll export credentials for now. thanks for your help!

Comment: @Mell can you mark the question as solved? This helps the community and anyone who stumble upon this question.

Answer (score 0):

You also have to specify the role arn on the backend.tf:

```
terraform {
    backend "s3" {
        bucket   = "your_bucket"
        key      = "your_key"
        region   = "us-east-1" (or whataver is the one you're using)
        role_arn = "arn:aws:iam::<account_id>:role/<role_name>"
    }
}
```